# tf.contrib.signal.stft returns an empty matrix

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, ffmpeg, jupyter-notebook

This is the piece of code I run:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

filename = 'song.mp3' # 30 second mp3 file
SAMPLES_PER_SEC = 44100

audio_binary = tf.read_file(filename)

pcm = tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio(audio_binary, file_format='mp3', samples_per_second=SAMPLES_PER_SEC, channel_count = 1)
stft = tf.contrib.signal.stft(pcm, frame_length=1024, frame_step=512, fft_length=1024)

sess.close()
```

The mp3 file is properly decoded because `print(pcm.eval().shape)` returns:

```
(1323119, 1)
```

And there are even some actual non-zero values when I print them with `print(pcm.eval()[1000:1010])`:

```
[[ 0.18793298]
 [ 0.16214484]
 [ 0.16022217]
 [ 0.15918455]
 [ 0.16428113]
 [ 0.19858395]
 [ 0.22861415]
 [ 0.2347789 ]
 [ 0.22684409]
 [ 0.20728172]]
```

But for some reason `print(stft.eval().shape)` evaluates to:

```
(1323119, 0, 513) # why the zero dimension?
```

And therefore `print(stft.eval())` is:

```
[]
```

According to [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/signal/stft) the second dimension of the `tf.contrib.signal.stft` output is equal to the number of frames. Why are there no frames though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio` returned a tensor of shape `(?, 1)` which is one signal of `?` samples.

However `tf.contrib.signal.stft` expects a `(signal_count, samples)` tensor as input, therefore one has to transpose it beforehand.

Modifying the call like this does the trick:

```
stft = tf.contrib.signal.stft(tf.transpose(pcm), frame_length=1024, frame_step=512, fft_length=1024)
```